# how can I call a nested global or local jquery variable into html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this problem I have tried for days but no success. Any help would be very appreciated.

I would like to call a variable from nested jQuery into html. The variable I have called it with the name "PROBLEM". I have even tried to make it global but when I update it locally inside the function

```
$(".dropdown dd ul li a").click(function() { }
```

the changes remain local. How can I do this? Thank you.
NB/I have UPDATED by  pasting the whole function. I found this function online and  modified it so that it performa  a select function with both image and text. I would like to know which selection it is like facebook when that happens so that I can change the SIGNUP page with a facebook page,

```
 <span =email>
```

the part above helps me know if its email or other social media site. 
on running the 
   alert(text)

displays

```
<span =email=""><img class="flag flagvisibility" src="media/Email_icon.png" alt="" style="margin-bottom:0px" height="30" width="30" align="left&quot;"> Email</span>
```

and I use

```
var n1 = text.indexOf("=") + 1;
            var n2 = text.indexOf("=", n1);// OR SIMPLY USE c=text.slice(text.indexOf("=")+1, text.indexOf("=", text.indexOf("=")+1))
            n3 = text.slice(n1, n2)
            PROBLEM[0] = text.slice(n1, n2)
```

to get the 1st and 2nd  indicies of equal sign "=" and from that i can extract if its email or other   social media sites. I hope this helps

Here is the whole

```
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var PROBLEM =[]
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".dropdown img.flag").addClass("flagvisibility");

        $(".dropdown dt a").click(function() {
            $(".dropdown dd ul").toggle();
            return false; //This is the important part
        });

        $(".dropdown dd ul li a").click(function() {
            var text = $(this).html();
            $(".dropdown dt a span").html(text);
            $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
            //$("#result").html(text);
            //$("#result").html("Selected value is: " + getSelectedValue("sample"));
            $("#result").html("Selected value is: " + text);
            var n1 = text.indexOf("=") + 1;
            var n2 = text.indexOf("=", n1);// OR SIMPLY USE c=text.slice(text.indexOf("=")+1, text.indexOf("=", text.indexOf("=")+1))
            n3 = text.slice(n1, n2)
            PROBLEM[0] = text.slice(n1, n2)
            //return false; //This is the important part
        })


        function getSelectedValue(id) {
            return $("#" + id).find("dt a span.value").html();
        }

        $(document).bind('click', function(e) {
            var $clicked = $(e.target);
            if (! $clicked.parents().hasClass("dropdown"))
                $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();

        });

        $("#flagSwitcher").click(function() {
            $(".dropdown img.flag").toggleClass("flagvisibility");
        });
    });


</script>


<dl id="sample" class="dropdown">
        <dt style="vertical-align:middle"><a href="#"><span ><img class="flag" src="media/Email_icon.png" alt="" width="30" height="30" align=left" style="margin-bottom:0px"/> Email</span></a></dt>
    <dd>
        <ul>
            <!--the use  of names like  email, face book in the span is just for some  dirty  steps in the javascript above .indexOf("=")-->
            <li><a href="#"><span =email><img class="flag" src="media/Email_icon.png" alt="" width="30" height="30" align=left" style="margin-bottom:0px" /> Email</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span =facebook><img class="flag" src="media/Facebook_icon.png" alt="" width="30" height="30" align=left" style="margin-bottom:0px" /> Facebook</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span =twitter><img class="flag" src="media/Twitter_icon.png" alt="" width="30" height="30" align=left" style="margin-bottom:0px" /> Twitter</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span =linkedin><img class="flag" src="media/Linkedin_icon.png" alt="" width="30" height="30" align=left" style="margin-bottom:0px" /> LinkedIn</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </dd>
</dl>
<span id="result">
```

Comment: You don't use it other than to assign a value to it. How are you testing this?

Comment: What do you want to do with the `PROBLEM` variable after you populate it?  The reason it generally doesn't work as a global is because the click handler runs some time in the future so the value in the `PROBLEM` variable is not present until AFTER the click is processed.  If you want to use `PROBLEM` in some other code, then call that code from within the click handler and pass the `PROBLEM` variable as an argument to that other function.

Comment: It looks like you are running the JS, then following a link, which would load a new page where the variable no longer exists.

Comment: or you can reset it after using the value of `PROBLEM` with `PROBLEM="";`. also i just want to state that the `var PROBLEM = [];` is an array and you are assigning values in the click handler instead of pushing.

Comment: Perhaps you have a typo or three?  Some of the lines of code you presented do not end with semicolons.  That could cause an error, preventing certain things from happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is caused because you're not preventing the hyperlinks default action from happening. You need to either use `return false;` or `event.preventDefault();` to stop the link from posting back.

```
var PROBLEM = [];
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".dropdown img.flag").addClass("flagvisibility");

    $(".dropdown dt a").click(function() {
        $(".dropdown dd ul").toggle();

        return false; //This is the important part
    });

    $(".dropdown dd ul li a").click(function() {

        var text = $(this).html();

        $(".dropdown dt a span").html(text);
        $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
        $("#result").html("Selected value is: " + text);

        var n1 = text.indexOf("=") + 1,
            n2 = text.indexOf("=", n1);

        n3 = text.slice(n1,n2);
        PROBLEM = text.slice(n1,n2);

        return false; //This is the important part
    }
});
```

Also your jQuery ready event is not well formed:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

}); // your missing this closing bracket.
```

Comment: thanks for your comment, I did not paste the whole jquery function but the remaining part is ok. I just don't know how to make local update to a global variable

Comment: @KevinOluoch what did you want to achieve with your code? You want a user to pick from a list of social networks in a dropdown list?

Comment: Thanks very  much for your reply actually I alredy made it work . The last line 
<span id="result"> is already doing what i wanted and it could just be embeded inthe html. The original code can be found here http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/144/A-Drop-Down-with-Icon-CSS-and-jQuery.html

Comment: the code in the link  changes a dropdown list by name and image , i wanted that whenever that happens, i send a message to also change the  login form to eithe  email or facebook in my app